# Pearson correlation condidency interval

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, pearson

I am newbie on statistic and need to do some simple correlation test on my thesis work,

I am following [this guilde](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/cor.test.html) to calculate person correlation between 2 sample result n1 and n2.

The input data:

> n1:
>   2 2 3 5 3 4 4 4 4 4 2 4 4 2 2 4 2 2 2 5 3 2 2 5 5 2 5 5 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 5 2 5 2
>
> n2:
>   2 2 3 5 3 4 4 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 2 3 5 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3
>   2 3 3

The function I call in R:

```
p = cor.test(n1,n2,method="pearson", conf.level=0.9)
```

The problem is: no matter what value I set to confidence interval `conf.level`, it all calculate to the same value; so parameter `conf.level` does not affect the correlation.

Why is it?  How could I make the confidence level affects Pearson correlation value?

Answer (score 1):

You can't!

In fact, from the definition of the correlation coefficient, confidence level only affects the confidence interval. In the case of R toolbox, according to [Correlation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/cor.test.html), **"confidence level for the returned confidence interval. Currently only used for the Pearson product moment correlation coefficient if there are at least 4 complete pairs of observations**"

See also: [Confidence interval](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/estimation/correlation_ci.html)